# .NET Framework 4.6 System.web

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.6, system.web

I'm writing a software in C# WPF with the framework 4.6.

I need to convert some HTML to text. 
The easiest way seems to be by using the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() method in the System.web library.

I can add this library with using System.Web, but it seems HttpUtility it still unrecognized.

How can I fix this ?

Edit : I also added the reference by the treeview in the solution explorer and it worked. I don't understand why though. I think it could be usefull to someone one day as I didn't find this solution there.

Comment: Use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx) instead, and you don't even have to add the reference to System.Web

Comment: Worked too. Adding the ref by the solution treeview was another solution.